# When I overlap an image and a canvas, I can't get it to stay in line

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Previously, I had a row of 5 canvas elements as follows, with dates displayed directly underneath each of them:

```
<div class="clock">

<div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart0" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day0"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date0"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart1" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day1"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date1"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart2" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day2"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date2"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart3" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day3"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date3"></div>
</div>
<div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart4" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day4"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date4"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add an image over the canvas's that is slightly transparent so whatever I draw on the canvas shows through. When I change the first clockwrapper to this, however:

```
    <img src="images/clock2.jpg" id="imgclock1" width="150" height="150" class="analog"/>
    <canvas id="piechart0" width="150" height="150" style="position: relative; top: -150px; left: 0px; opacity: .5"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day0"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date0"></div>
```

The next four canvas's drop down a line and I have to change the top style of piechart0 to -150px so they can overlap. Here is the style for each of the classes:

```
canvas {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 25%
}
.date {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.date1 {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.clockwrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

What do I need to change with the img style so that **A.)** The canvas and image can overlap (this was accomplished with the top: -150px for the canvas) and **B.)** All of the canvas objects appear on the same line.

Comment: I recommend changing `display: inline;` to `inline-block` for most of your containers and using `position: relative;` with `top, left, bottom` and `right` CSS attributes to position it inside the container that holds both the canvas and the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start for you

```css
.clock {
    white-space: nowrap;     /*  keep all wrappers on same line  */
}
canvas {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 25%
}
.date {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.date1 {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.clockwrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: relative;
    background: #eee;    /*  just to get the wrapper visible in this sample  */
}
.clockwrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;          /*  adjust to get it in position  */
    top: 30px;           /*  adjust to get it in position  */
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #f99;    /*  just to get the img visible in this sample  */
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart0" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day0"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date0"></div>
   <img src="images/clock2.jpg" id="imgclock1" width="150" height="150" class="analog"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart1" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day1"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart2" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day2"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart3" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day3"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clockwrapper">
    <canvas id="piechart4" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    <div class="date" id="day4"></div>
    <div class="date1" id="date4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```